# how to insert data available for both sender and receiver in solidity?

Tags: reactjs, solidity, web3js

---------Solidity---------
This is a create request:

```
function createRequest(Requests memory rqst) external
{
        Rqst[msg.sender].push(Requests({
            status:rqst.status,
            amount:rqst.amount,
            description:rqst.description
        }));
}
```

This is the get request:

```
function getRequest(uint requestIndex) external view returns (Requests memory)
{
        Requests storage rqst = Rqst[msg.sender][requestIndex];
        return rqst;
}
```

---------end of Solidity---------

---------React.js---------

```
  const createRequest =  async () => {
    await contract.methods.createRequest(['pending',amount, description]).send({ from: defaultAccount });
  }
```

Note: in createRequest, defaultAccount is the current metamask login, which is the employee.

This method getRequests is called if the metamask login is the manager.

```
  const getRequests =  async (contract, defaultAccount) => {
    const f = async () => {
      const len = await contract.methods.getRequestount().call({ from: defaultAccount });
      console.log("len",len)
      let iterator = 0
      let contain = []
      while ( iterator <= len) {
        try {
          console.log("iterator",iterator)
          let o = await contract.methods.getRequest(String(iterator)).call({ from: defaultAccount });
          if (o[0] !== '') {
            contain.push({
              status: o['status'],
              amount: o['amount'],
              description: o['description']
            })
          }
          else {
            console.log('The index ' + iterator + ' is empty');
          }
        } catch {
          console.log('Failed to get requests ' + iterator);
        }
        iterator++;
      }
      return contain
    }
    let c = await f()
    dispatch(setRequests(c))
  }
```

----------end of React.js--------

I am creating a request to my manager.
The manager has an admin that displays a list of request.

When I `getRequest()` web3 returns `MetaMask - RPC Error: execution reverted`.

I tried creating request using the manager and then display the requests, it works perfectly.

Comment: How exactly do you invoke the `getRequest()` method from web3 JS? Can you share the snippet? I'm assuming that the `msg.sender` might not be the same, or you might be accessing `requestIndex` that is out of bounds.

Comment: @PetrHejda hello, i updated it, added the reactjs codes `getRequests` and `createRequest`. trust me this codes works